# Ask Allah a spouse whom I love

Tags: nikah, wife, husband, love

I love a girl. Don't know how much she loves me. But she has a little bit of affection for me, I know. We were in a relationship. But some facts come and it is now impossible to be with her. While we were in relationship I thought we are not doing the right thing. But couldn't prevent myself from this.

Now my heart desires to be with her as her husband. So I make dua to Allah. I pray like, Allah please accept her as my righteous wife. Give us a happy life. And all the difficulties that have arisen please make them easier to face. Please make the way easy.

I want no more sin with her. I regret that I did a lot of sin. Will Allah listen to me? Or are the duas correct? Are they prohibited? Or can anyone give me any good suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

Asking for something halal **isn't prohibited** at all.

Just keep repenting, **say astagh-fer-allah** hundreds of times a day,he would help you ISA

**Ask him** ,if she is right for you, help you marry her, otherwise if isn't ask to make you forget about her and full your hert with satisfaction about Allah choice.

**Trust me I have tried**, I have forgotten her immediately after finding she isn't suitable for me and something wrong about her.

**Don't despair at all**